# VMware ESXI Behind ASA5506-Xs using Public IP is Not Communicating

Tags: vmware-esxi, nat, cisco-asa, static-routes

Here is the lay of the land. Everything works but I cannot get data flow from ESXI Server or it's VM's
I want them using public addresses from behind the router.

The Vmware ESXI Hypervisor on a Bare Metal Proliant ml150 gen9 system unit.

```
NIC Static IP: 72.xxx.xxx.112 
Gateway:72.xxx.xxx.1 
Guest VM1 IP: 72.xxx.xxx.111  
Guest VM2 IP: 72.xxx.xxx.110 
Guest VM3 IP: 72.xxx.xxx.108
```

Cisco ASA5506-X Router with 1 Outside Connection on Interface1
The Router is providing service for everything except this esxi server.

```
Interface1: outside,DSL IP 72.xxx.xxx.109 SUB 255.255.255.128 GATE 72.xxx.xxx.1
Interface2: Inside, network - Cisco SG300-10 Managed Switch for Workstation, Printer, Soon w/ VOIP.
Interface3: wifi, bridge - Laptops, Tablets,Cell Browsers, TV, Echo / Alexa.
Interface4:Disabled
Interface5:Disabled
Interface6:Disabled
Interface7:server-dmz2 - The Secondary NIC on the ESXI Server - When Both enabled = Fault Tolerant, Outgoing Load Balanced.
Interface8:server-dmz -   The Primary NIC on the ESXI Server -
```

Here is some config output from the router
Result of the command: `show interface`

```
Interface GigabitEthernet1/1 "outside", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(100 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 72.xxx.xxx.109, subnet mask 255.255.255.128
    42446874 packets input, 6101930958 bytes, 37825750 no buffer
    Received 6026 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    2426487 packets output, 7652518715443 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (924/862)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/948)
  Traffic Statistics for "outside":
    4621128 packets input, 6018070964 bytes
    2426487 packets output, 224976920 bytes
    23171 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 1 pkts/sec,  228 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 1 pkts/sec,  459 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 4 pkts/sec,  1449 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 4 pkts/sec,  686 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
Interface GigabitEthernet1/2 "inside", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 10.10.10.3, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
    4079498 packets input, 332114060 bytes, 1396 no buffer
    Received 3470688 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    725392 packets output, 14586382412068 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (915/875)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/977)
  Traffic Statistics for "inside":
    4077061 packets input, 256389121 bytes
    725392 packets output, 610148343 bytes
    108164 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 31 pkts/sec,  1601 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 2 pkts/sec,  1464 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 35 pkts/sec,  2196 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 9 pkts/sec,  3091 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
Interface GigabitEthernet1/3 "wifi", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 10.10.11.2, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
    2106732 packets input, 187046703 bytes, 8478 no buffer
    Received 7287 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    4048977 packets output, 178622247365600 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (984/863)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/984)
  Traffic Statistics for "wifi":
    2098209 packets input, 148734685 bytes
    4048977 packets output, 5512267580 bytes
    62873 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 1 pkts/sec,  380 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 1 pkts/sec,  200 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 1 pkts/sec,  108 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  70 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
Interface GigabitEthernet1/4 "", is administratively down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex, Auto-Speed
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    Available but not configured via nameif
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU not set
    IP address unassigned
    0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
    Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
Interface GigabitEthernet1/5 "", is administratively down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex, Auto-Speed
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    Available but not configured via nameif
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU not set
    IP address unassigned
    0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
    Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
Interface GigabitEthernet1/6 "", is administratively down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex, Auto-Speed
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    Available but not configured via nameif
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU not set
    IP address unassigned
    0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
    Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1023)
Interface GigabitEthernet1/7 "server-dmz-2", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 10.10.7.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.252
    314 packets input, 6656 bytes, 210 no buffer
    Received 103 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    1 packets output, 669248 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (919/919)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1022)
  Traffic Statistics for "server-dmz-2":
    103 packets input, 4732 bytes
    1 packets output, 28 bytes
    51 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 0 pkts/sec,  6 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
Interface GigabitEthernet1/8 "server-dmz", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Accelerator rev01, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 10.10.12.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.248
    521534 packets input, 85504 bytes, 520198 no buffer
    Received 1321 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    1 packets output, 1732928 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (968/894)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (1023/1022)
  Traffic Statistics for "server-dmz":
    1319 packets input, 60596 bytes
    1 packets output, 28 bytes
    237 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 0 pkts/sec,  32 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 0 pkts/sec,  9 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
Interface Management1/1 "asa1manager", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is en_vtun rev00, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)
    Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
    MAC address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, MTU 1500
    IP address 192.168.1.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
    3471177 packets input, 208610041 bytes, 0 no buffer
    Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 pause input, 0 resume input
    0 L2 decode drops
    48 packets output, 2558 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 pause output, 0 resume output
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
    input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (0/0)
    output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (0/0)
  Traffic Statistics for "asa1manager":
    3471177 packets input, 160013563 bytes
    48 packets output, 1886 bytes
    5968 packets dropped
      1 minute input rate 28 pkts/sec,  1312 bytes/sec
      1 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      1 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
      5 minute input rate 28 pkts/sec,  1304 bytes/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 pkts/sec,  0 bytes/sec
      5 minute drop rate, 0 pkts/sec
    Management-only interface. Blocked 0 through-the-device packets
```

Result of the command: "show xlate"

```
28 in use, 228 most used
Flags: D - DNS, e - extended, I - identity, i - dynamic, r - portmap,
       s - static, T - twice, N - net-to-net
NAT from inside:0.0.0.0/0 to outside:0.0.0.0/0
    flags sIT idle 12:09:09 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from outside:10.10.13.0/24 to inside:10.10.13.0/24
    flags sIT idle 12:09:09 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from inside:0.0.0.0/0 to inside:0.0.0.0/0
    flags sIT idle 12:09:09 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from inside:10.10.13.0/24 to inside:10.10.13.0/24
    flags sIT idle 12:09:09 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from outside:0.0.0.0/0 to any:0.0.0.0/0
    flags sIT idle 11:00:25 timeout 0:00:00

UDP PAT from any:10.10.11.55/33479 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/33479 flags ri idle 0:01:23 timeout 0:00:30
UDP PAT from any:10.10.11.55/38950 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/38950 flags ri idle 0:01:28 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.55/52200 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/52200 flags ri idle 1:12:38 timeout 0:00:30
UDP PAT from any:10.10.11.55/47619 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/47619 flags ri idle 17:39:20 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.54/57218 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/57218 flags ri idle 17:39:28 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.56/44146 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/44146 flags ri idle 0:00:15 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.56/44145 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/44145 flags ri idle 0:00:15 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.56/36256 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/36256 flags ri idle 0:03:05 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.56/48011 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/48011 flags ri idle 17:39:01 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.51/45079 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/45079 flags ri idle 0:04:36 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.51/37669 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/37669 flags ri idle 0:09:37 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.52/57376 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/57376 flags ri idle 0:51:43 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.11.52/58383 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/58383 flags ri idle 17:36:54 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8263 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8263 flags ri idle 0:00:00 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8261 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8261 flags ri idle 0:00:09 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8260 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8260 flags ri idle 0:00:18 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8222 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8222 flags ri idle 0:03:42 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8208 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8208 flags ri idle 0:04:08 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/8189 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/8189 flags ri idle 0:05:43 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/7248 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/7248 flags ri idle 0:56:16 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/7244 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/7244 flags ri idle 0:56:17 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/7231 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/7231 flags ri idle 0:56:21 timeout 0:00:30
TCP PAT from any:10.10.10.51/7111 to outside:72.xxx.xxx.109/7111 flags ri idle 0:56:45 timeout 0:00:30
```

Result of the command: `show tech-support`

```
Frame drop:
  Invalid encapsulation (invalid-encap)                                       45
  No route to host (no-route)                                                 51
  Reverse-path verify failed (rpf-violated)                                 2989
  Flow is denied by configured rule (acl-drop)                             52033
  First TCP packet not SYN (tcp-not-syn)                                    2887
  Bad TCP flags (bad-tcp-flags)                                                4
  TCP failed 3 way handshake (tcp-3whs-failed)                                14
  TCP RST/FIN out of order (tcp-rstfin-ooo)                                 3533
  TCP SYNACK on established conn (tcp-synack-ooo)                             18
  TCP packet SEQ past window (tcp-seq-past-win)                               14
  TCP RST/SYN in window (tcp-rst-syn-in-win)                                   1
  TCP packet failed PAWS test (tcp-paws-fail)                                  2
  Slowpath security checks failed (sp-security-failed)                      9070
  ICMP Inspect seq num not matched (inspect-icmp-seq-num-not-matched)          3
  DNS Inspect invalid packet (inspect-dns-invalid-pak)                         4
  DNS Inspect invalid domain label (inspect-dns-invalid-domain-label)          4
  DNS Inspect packet too long (inspect-dns-pak-too-long)                       5
  DNS Inspect id not matched (inspect-dns-id-not-matched)                    615
  FP L2 rule drop (l2_acl)                                                129502
  Interface is down (interface-down)                                          27
  Dropped pending packets in a closed socket (np-socket-closed)               87
  NAT failed (nat-xlate-failed)                                                6

Last clearing: Never

Flow drop:
  NAT reverse path failed (nat-rpf-failed)                                   144
  Inspection failure (inspect-fail)                                         1350
  SSL bad record detected (ssl-bad-record-detect)                              2
  SSL handshake failed (ssl-handshake-failed)                                  4

Last clearing: Never
------------------ show service-policy ------------------


Global policy: 
  Service-policy: global_policy
    Class-map: inspection_default
      Inspect: dns preset_dns_map, packet 37318, lock fail 0, drop 628, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
        message-length maximum client auto, drop 0
        message-length maximum 512, drop 0
        dns-guard, count 17223
        protocol-enforcement, drop 4
        nat-rewrite, count 0
      Inspect: ftp, packet 2, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: h323 h225 _default_h323_map, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
               tcp-proxy: bytes in buffer 0, bytes dropped 0
        h245-tunnel-block drops 0 connection
      Inspect: h323 ras _default_h323_map, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
        h245-tunnel-block drops 0 connection
      Inspect: rsh, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: rtsp, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
               tcp-proxy: bytes in buffer 0, bytes dropped 0
      Inspect: esmtp _default_esmtp_map, packet 1449, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
        mask-banner, count 1
        match cmd line length gt 512 
          drop-connection log, packet 0
        match cmd RCPT count gt 100 
          drop-connection log, packet 0
        match body line length gt 998 
          log, packet 0
        match header line length gt 998 
          drop-connection log, packet 0
        match sender-address length gt 320 
          drop-connection log, packet 0
        match MIME filename length gt 255 
          drop-connection log, packet 0
        match ehlo-reply-parameter others 
          mask, packet 0
      Inspect: sqlnet, packet 7, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: skinny , packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
               tcp-proxy: bytes in buffer 0, bytes dropped 0
      Inspect: sunrpc, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
               tcp-proxy: bytes in buffer 0, bytes dropped 0
      Inspect: xdmcp, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: sip , packet 93, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
               tcp-proxy: bytes in buffer 0, bytes dropped 0
      Inspect: netbios, packet 8, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: tftp, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
      Inspect: ip-options _default_ip_options_map, packet 0, lock fail 0, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
        Router Alert:  allow 0, clear 0
    Class-map: class-default

      Default Queueing  Packet recieved 0, sent 0, attack 0
      SFR: card status Up, mode fail-open monitor-only
        packet input 0, packet output 6947513, drop 0, reset-drop 0

Interface outside:
  Service-policy: outside-policy-srb
    Class-map: outside-class-srb1
      SFR: card status Up, mode fail-open monitor-only
        packet input 0, packet output 6639, drop 0, reset-drop 0

------------------ show capture ------------------


------------------ show history ------------------


------------------ show firewall ------------------

Firewall mode: Router

------------------ show running-config ------------------

: Saved

: 
: Serial Number: JAD191100PJ
: Hardware:   ASA5506, 4096 MB RAM, CPU Atom C2000 series 1250 MHz, 1 CPU (4 cores)
:
ASA Version 9.3(2)2 
!
hostname asa1
enable password <removed>
names
dns-guard
ip local pool RHQSalesVPN 10.10.13.100-10.10.13.150 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 72.xxx.xxx.109 255.255.255.128 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 95
 ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 nameif wifi
 security-level 95
 ip address 10.10.11.2 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 nameif server-dmz-2
 security-level 95
 ip address 10.10.7.1 255.255.255.252 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 nameif server-dmz
 security-level 95
 ip address 10.10.12.1 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 nameif asa1manager
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone HST -10
dns domain-lookup outside
dns domain-lookup inside
dns domain-lookup server-dmz
dns domain-lookup asa1manager
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 72.xxx.80.4
 name-server 72.xxx.80.12
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.13.0_24
 subnet 10.10.13.0 255.255.255.0
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx108
 host 72.xxx.xxx.108
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx110
 host 72.xxx.xxx.110
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx111
 host 72.xxx.xxx.111
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx112
 host 72.xxx.xxx.112
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx24
 host 72.xxx.xxx.24
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx25
 host 72.xxx.xxx.25
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx26
 host 72.xxx.xxx.26
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx27
 host 72.xxx.xxx.27
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx28
 host 72.xxx.xxx.28
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx29
 host 72.xxx.xxx.29
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx30
 host 72.xxx.xxx.30
object network IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx31
 host 72.xxx.xxx.31
object network server-interface-nat
 host 10.10.12.1
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
object-group network inside-networks-group
 network-object 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.10.12.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.10.7.0 255.255.255.248
object-group network IP-GROUP-HTEL
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx108
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx110
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx111
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx112
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx24
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx25
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx26
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx27
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx28
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx29
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx30
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx31
object-group network IP-SERVERS-GROUP
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx108
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx110
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx111
 network-object object IP-OBJ-72xxxxxx112
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any object-group IP-SERVERS-GROUP 
access-list rainbowtunnel_splitTunnelAcl standard permit any4 
access-list server-dmz_access_in extended permit ip any object-group IP-SERVERS-GROUP 
access-list Server-NIC2_access_in extended permit ip interface outside interface inside 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm warnings
no logging message 418001
no logging message 419002
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu wifi 1500
mtu server-dmz 1500
mtu asa1manager 1500
mtu server-dmz-2 1500
ip verify reverse-path interface outside
ip verify reverse-path interface inside
ip verify reverse-path interface wifi
ip verify reverse-path interface server-dmz
ip verify reverse-path interface asa1manager
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.13.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.13.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,inside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.13.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.13.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (any,outside) source dynamic inside-networks-group interface
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group server-dmz_access_in in interface server-dmz
access-group Server-NIC2_access_in in interface server-dmz-2
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 72.xxx.xxx.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL 
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 asa1manager
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 wifi
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
auth-prompt prompt Dare Enter?? 
auth-prompt accept Blessed 
auth-prompt reject Cast Out 

Message #309 : 
INFO: Power-On Self-Test in process.
Message #310 : .Message #311 : .Message #312 : .Message #313 : .Message #314 : .Message #315 : .Message #316 : .Message #317 : .Message #318 : .Message #319 : .Message #320 : .Message #321 : .Message #322 : .Message #323 : .Message #324 : .Message #325 : .Message #326 : .Message #327 : .Message #328 : .Message #329 : .Message #330 : .Message #331 : .Message #332 : .Message #333 : .Message #334 : .Message #335 : .Message #336 : .Message #337 : .Message #338 : .Message #339 : .Message #340 : .Message #341 : .Message #342 : .Message #343 : .Message #344 : .Message #345 : .Message #346 : .Message #347 : .Message #348 : .Message #349 : .Message #350 : .Message #351 : .Message #352 : .Message #353 : .Message #354 : .Message #355 : .Message #356 : .Message #357 : .Message #358 : .Message #359 : .Message #360 : .Message #361 : .Message #362 : .Message #363 : .Message #364 : .Message #365 : .Message #366 : .Message #367 : .Message #368 : .Message #369 : .Message #370 : .Message #371 : .Message #372 : .Message #373 : .Message #374 : .Message #375 : .Message #376 : .Message #377 : .Message #378 : .Message #379 : .Message #380 : .Message #381 : 
INFO: Power-On Self-Test complete.
Message #382 : 
INFO: Starting HW-DRBG health test...Message #383 : 
INFO: HW-DRBG health test passed.
Message #384 : 
INFO: Starting SW-DRBG health test...Message #385 : 
INFO: SW-DRBG health test passed.
```

Comment: You have configured the ESXi interfaces in fault tolerant/load balanced mode on the host yet connected them directly to routed interfaces on the ASA on different subnets. I can only comment as I did your now deleted first attempt, you need to look at the basics of routing (and complement it with the basics of switching). Suggestion: read a bit about basic L2(switching/vlan), L3(routing). Then try to get the ESXi/ASA to work like the rest of your home network: configure it to do outbound traffic. When you've succeeded try to configure it to accept inbound traffic through the public interface.

Comment: Ok Erik,  I will.   I was hoping that you would spot this.   Thank you

Comment: Sven,  Thank you for improving the readability of this.

Comment: I Gave up on this after speaking with Cisco TAC,  Put the ASA Interface on a private IP and the ESXI on the same private lan and the VM's and their VPS Servers also configured to use the private lan and the websites to use the public addresses and with proper natting, The Inside and Outside and Wifi All have internet access and they all have access to the DMZ Server. All Public Websites are visible.  The only problem I have is that the bridged wifi router clients behind the ASA are not achieving access to the Server on the DMZ.   Im sure it is just another nat to be done.  Ugh...